# jQuery validator for check whether name starts with alphabetic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form which I'm using a jquery validator, where I want to check, when the user enters a name, the name can contain special characters but it should always start with a alphabetical character. Can someone please advice how to proceed?

```
full_name: {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'The Full Name field is required'
        },
        stringLength: {
            max: 100,
            message: 'The Full Name must be  less than 100 characters long'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: which is the validation framework used

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/validators/

Comment: Read the jQuery Validator Plugin documentation about regex validation.  You can use a regex like: 
`/[a-z].*/i`

Answer (score 0):

Use [regexp](http://formvalidation.io/validators/regexp/) like,

```
validators: {
    regexp: {
       regexp: /^[a-z]{1}/i, //^ -> Starts with,[a-z] -> characters to match, {1} -> Only the first character, i for case insesetivity
       message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
    }
}
```

You can use regex `/^[a-z].*/i` also, where `.*` can be any character

Comment: Not exactly what he was asking for, since it should start with a letter, but can contain other characters after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( yourstring.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/) ) {
         return true
     }
```